# first inverse moment of hypergeometric distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, summation, hypergeometric-function

I am interested in the Petersen Estimator for the Mark and Recapture method. By standardarguments one can construct the estimator via Maximum-Likelihood as follows:

$$\hat N(k)=\frac{R m}{k}$$

Where $\hat N$ is the unknown population size. R is the integer number of marked individuals and $m$ is the number of recaptured individuals. The small $k$ is the number of marked individuals among the captured ones.

Rewriting $\hat N$ as a random variable, we can write:
$$\hat N=\frac{Rm}{X}$$
where $X$ has a hypergeometric distribution.

Since the probability of not recapturing any marked individuals is not zero, the estimator is not really well defined. So I wanted to look at
$$\hat N_1:=\frac{Rm}{X}\mathbf 1_{X>0}$$

Computing the expectation of this estimator I started with
$$\mathbf E\left[\frac1X\mathbf 1_{X>0}\right]=\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1k\frac{\binom{R}{k}\binom{N-R}{m-k}}{\binom{N}{m}}$$

I am not quite sure, what to do here. The $k$ is somewhat troublesome. I tried wolfram already, but I do not seek for formulas containing the generalized hypergeometric function and was hoping for an eplicit result.

I do know, that the modified version is better, but I am explicitly interested in this expectation.

Comment: Mathematica gives the expected value as $$\frac{R \binom{N-R}{m-1} \, _4F_3(1,1,1-m,1-R;2,2,-m+N-R+2;1)}{\binom{N}{m}}.$$ This may very well reduce to something nicer looking.